# Randomly getting ajax status as 0 in safari browser

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari, safari-extension

I do a post ajax request to fetch user details.At times,when I do a request I get response status as 0(An error occurred trying to load the resource) but most of the times I get a valid response from server for the same url.I have read few posts with respect to my issue and all it stated was "when you make a cross domain status will be returned as 0" but this is not my case as I am making request from the same domain.

The ajax send event is not fired whenever I get status as 0.Has anyone faced this kind of issue?Is it related to safari browser?It seems to work fine in chrome and firefox.Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the relevant code you're using to make the Ajax request, and the server code that you're calling. I'd say that's the best way to start diagnosing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue when working with webkit based browsers in the past.  After enabling failed request tracing on the web server I found that the request was not even being sent from the browser.  Enabling detailed debugging within the web browser pointed to a bug with the browser itself.  Faced with an outstanding bug in the browser, I finally arrived at the following solution.

This code will retry the ajax request in the event that the status code returned from the browser is 0.  In all other respects it will function just as jQuery's ajax function. You can configure the number of times that the code will reattempt to send the request.

```
function AjaxRetry(settings, maxTries, interval) {
  var self = this;
  this.settings = settings;
  this.maxTries = typeof maxTries === "number" ? maxTries : 0;
  this.completedTries = 0;
  this.interval = typeof interval === "number" ? interval : 0;

  return tryAjax().promise();

  function tryAjax(deferred) {
    var d = deferred || $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(self.settings)
        .done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            self.completedTries += 1;
            d.resolve(data, status, xhr);
            self.done = true;
        })
        .fail(function (xhr, textStatus, error) {

            self.completedTries += 1;
            var attemptRetry = false;

            // Added in an attempt to handle the ajax errors that appear to be a flaw in the Intermec HTML5 Browser.
            // Example error in browser debug log: Curl ERROR: Failed sending data to the peer for url
            // This appears to be CURLE_SEND_ERROR (55) - Failed sending network data.  https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

            // This code will retry any ajax requests that fail due to the HTML5 browser CURL error
            if (typeof (xhr) !== 'undefined' && typeof (textStatus) !== 'undefined' && typeof (error) !== 'undefined') {
                if (xhr.readyState === 0 && xhr.responseJSON === undefined && xhr.status === 0 && xhr.statusText === 'error') {
                    attemptRetry = true;
                }
            }

            if (self.completedTries < self.maxTries && attemptRetry === true) {
                //console.log("Waiting " + interval + "ms before retrying...");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tryAjax(d);
                }, self.interval);
            } else {
                d.reject(xhr, textStatus, error);
            }

        });
    return d;
}
```

}